# ListFragment in Tablet app for android, not using full screen?

Tags: android-layout, android

Example image here:

[image]

Used the tutorial from here:

http://www.kaloer.com/making-your-app-tablet-friendly-3-steps

So I am sure I am missing some setting or line that I just didn't see.  So the sides of the image are right its a tablet emulator skin.  Though the main view looks like it is insisting on some lower res version in landscape mode.  The really odd thing is I have a layout-xlarge folder that is getting utilized so it "knows" its a large screen to use but isn't using it.  Any ideas what I did wrong?  Ideally the list would be on the far left and wider and the other side would be much larger as well?

oh and the StudioTab Icon and title would be on the far left too, just cannot figure out what little bit I am missing to make that happen?

Comment: Show us your layout xml files.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your maifest.xml file

```
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens = "true"
    android:normalScreens = "true"
    android:largeScreens = "true"
    android:xlargeScreens ="true"
    android:anyDensity = "true"/>
```

Also worth making sure that your layout dimensions units are `dp` instead of `px`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't missed anything from tutorial.

Also, Emulators are not reliable. Views with fragments on emulators doesn't show up as it should. See if you can run it on a real-device.

Comment: thanks I will try that.  I noticed (and seemingly recently) that the emulator is PAINFULLY slow.

Comment: Yah checked on device, indeed... it looks the same so ill go back through the tutorial with a fine toothed comb.  The tut had no way to setup the project as far as I could tell so maybe the hang up is somewhere there too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

to the manifest.